# Is it possible to display local variables tool tips text without hovering in Visual Studio?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to enable Visual Studio to display all local, available, variables as tool tips text without hovering? It would be convenient.

(I know I see them can see the Locals window)

Comment: Do you want to see the values (as in the Locals window) or the normal tooltip / documentation for the variables? And do you want to see all tooltips at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I want tooltips for all available variables so I dont have to open the locals window

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to "pin" them by clicking the thumbtack in the corner of the value.
They will then remain displayed.

Steps:

Set a breakpoint and hover over the value, you should see a thumbtack at the right end.

Click the thumbtack to pin the value.

Comment: It's not entirely "without hovering" but I think this is as close as you can get - given that the OP already knows about the Locals window.

Comment: Yes, those are the only two ways I know of. I just double checked vs2012 as well. Thanks.